# how to handle array of buttons handle click event in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I my react class component I tried it this way. But as soon as it renders the alert popup keeps coming all the time without any button click.

```
onHandleOnClick(data, e) {
console.log(data);
alert("got it" + data);
  }

renderRating(){
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
return arr.map((val) => {
  return (
    <button
     
      onClick={this.onHandleOnClick(val)}
    >
      {val}
    </button>
  );
 });
};

render() {
return (
  <div>
    {this.renderRating()}
 </div>
)
}
```

I am new in React. How do I do it?

Comment: You're calling the function instead of assigning it to the onClick event. Instead pass an anonymous function `onClick={(e) => this.onHandleOnClick(val, e)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function instead of assigning it to the onClick event.

Since you need to pass a parameter to the callback you can pass an anonymous function to `onClick`. Note that to also capture the `event` that React passes implicitly you should pass this as an argument in the anonymous function.

```
onClick={(e) => this.onHandleOnClick(val, e)}
```